# Can't use git repositories from other collections

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops

I moved some of my git repos to another collection but now all build which require at least one of the moved repositories are failing:

```
2019-03-20T14:50:49.5273620Z fatal: unable to access 'http://srcctl/Komponenten/_git/SKControls/': The requested URL returned error: 500
2019-03-20T14:50:49.5274518Z fatal: clone of 'http://srcctl/Komponenten/_git/SKControls' into submodule path 'C:/agent/_work/1/s/SKControls' failed
```

If I move the repos back to the original collection everything works fine again.

Has anyone an idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: can you share your "Get Sources" step?

Comment: I posted it on pastebin: https://pastebin.com/k7Zkij2C